# How to get Decimal | None field type in pydantic with condecimal?

Tags: python, pydantic, typing

I am creating a model where the field is constrained by decimal places and is positive.
I could just create a custom validator, but I was hoping to have condecimal work.

```
class Example(BaseModel):
  some_field: Optional[condecimal(ge=0.01, decimal_places=2)] = Field(alias="Some alias")
```

`some_field` is type `Any | None` but I would like to have it type `float | None`

I have also tried doing

```
some_field: Optional[float] = Field(alias="Some alias", ge=0.01, decimal_places=2)
```

but this gives `ValueError: On field "some_field" the following field constraints are set but not enforced: decimal_places.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the error for second version because `float` and `decimal` are different types (see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html)). A `float` cannot be constrained to the decimal places, but a `decimal` can.

You can fix it like this:

```py
from typing import Optional
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from decimal import Decimal


class Example(BaseModel):
  some_field: Optional[Decimal] = Field(ge=0.01, decimal_places=2)


Example(some_field=0.11)
>>> Example(some_field=Decimal('0.11'))
```

Comment: I used `field: Decimal = Field(ge=Decimal("0"))` and found `mypy` complained `src/models.py:164: error: Argument "ge" to "Field" has incompatible type "Decimal"; expected "float | None"  [arg-type]` even though Pydantic 2 has it [documented](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/types/#pydantic.types.condecimal).

Comment: Just look at the definition of the [Field](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/fields/). Mypy rightfully complains about the type.

Comment: That's right @Plagon, but the Pydantic documentation gives the type accepted by the `ge` argument as `int | Decimal | None`. That's my point. If you're simply bracketing around zero or an integer value this is ok but you'll lose accuracy if you need to bracket around a real number. In particular for the OP's question `0.01` as used is actually `Decimal('0.01000000000000000020816681711721685132943093776702880859375')`

Comment: @NeilG I understand your point, but is this ever an issue with `Decimal` where we do not use the full precision?

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to say. This isn't an issue with `Decimal`, it's not an issue with `float` either, that's just the way they work. As you point out it's not an issue with `mypy` either. It's an issue with Pydantic. Pydantic is using a `float` argument to constrain a `Decimal`, even though they document the argument as `Decimal`. At the very least it's a documentation issue but if you took that view surely you'd also add "align types of constraint arguments" to the TODO list. Absolutely it's an issue. OP cannot use `Field(ge=Decimal("0.01"))`. It's impossible.